# Get real entry names from other mysql tables, when main table contains these items ID

Tags: php, mysql

I cant find good solution to get information from other mysql tables when I have Main table (PC) which are connected to other tables (cpu, ram, hdd..). In PC table there is other components IDs (cpu, ram, hdd..).

There is the code which I am using:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM pc ORDER by id";
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
$result = mysql_query ($query);
$i=1;
echo '<table border = "1">';
echo '<tr><td><b>Nr.</b></td><td><b>CPU:</b></td><td><b>RAM</b></td><td><b>HDD</b></td><td><b>MB</b></td><td><b>GPU</b></td><td><b>Monitor</b></td></tr>';
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$proc = $nt['proc_id'];
$ram = $nt['ram_id'];
$hdd = $nt['hdd_id'];
$mb = $nt['mot_id'];
$gpu = $nt['gpu_id'];
$mon = $nt['monit_id'];

echo '<tr><td><b>'.$i++.'.</b></td><td>'.$proc.'</td><td>'.$ram.'</td><td>'.$hdd.'</td><td>'.$mb.'</td><td>'.$gpu.'</td><td>'.$mon.'</td></tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

```
_______________________________
|Nr.  CPU  RAM  GPU HDD MONITOR |
| 1    1     2    1   2     2   |
---------------------------------
```

I'm getting the list of parts ID numbers, but instead of this I need to print real names of these components which is in other tables,not IDs. So my question is how to use IDs which are in PC table to get item name containing that ID. For example:

```
________________________________________________________
|Nr.  CPU        RAM      GPU        HDD     MONITOR    |
| 1  Intel    2gb adata    GTX 460   WD 1tb     LCD..   |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Hope you understood my question, thanks.

Comment: you need to consider using LEFT JOIN in mysql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pc 
ORDER by id
```

to something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM PC 
LEFT JOIN RAM on PC.Ram_ID = Ram.ID
LEFT JOIN GPU on PC.GPUID = GPU.ID
...
ORDER BY PC.ID
```

For an improved understanding of Joins see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your table structures, so here is some psuedo code.  In your SQL query, you need to join to the other tables.  Also, I don't know if you have any nulls in any of your columns, so you may need to do `LEFT JOINS` instead of `INNER`.  JOINS unite data from two or more tables, based on a relationship between certain columns in these tables.. Since your RealNames are in other tables than pc, you have to bring them in to the query to get the RealNames.  `INNER JOIN` will bring back anything that matches in both tables.  `LEFT JOIN` will give you all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table - so if for example you have a null monitor, you'll need a `LEFT` or the row will not return at all.  Research joins!

```
SELECT pc.Id,PC.RealName,cpu.cpuId,cpu.RealName, ram.ramId ,ram.RealName,hdd.hddId          ,hdd.RealName,...
FROM pc  
INNER JOIN cpu ON cpu.cpuId = pc.cpu
INNER JOIN ram ON ram.ramId = pc.ram 
INNER JOIN hdd ON hdd.hddId = pc.hdd 
...
ORDER by pc.id
```